# migrating an application from Jboss 7.1 AS to Jboss EAP 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

Will applications developed using Jboss 7.1 AS work on Jboss 6 EAP? What are some of the things I should look out for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are migrating to EAP 6.0.x the only thing that might affect you is change in logging that can result in no logs being displayed.
To fix that you can set -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false 
Or set it permanently https://community.jboss.org/thread/220732

Beyond that there should be no big issues, but it mostly depends on your application that anything else.
EAP 6.0.x is basically 7.1.1.Final with tons of bugs fixed.

But if you are upgrading to EAP 6.1.x (currently there is 6.1.0.Alpha1 freely available)
There might be some bigger changes, but again upgrading from 7.1.1 to any EAP should be as simple as using old standalone.xml when starting EAP and it should automatically upgrade all configuration.

Given that there ware many changes & new features in EAP6.1 there might be some issues with your application, but again it really depends on what your application do and how.

Comment: thanks @ctomc! Just deployed the app to EAP 6.0. Works fine! :)